# Bullet Point showing up when it's not supposed to

Tags: html, css

I have a verticle navigation bar that has options that appear after you hover over the first option. When I have margins to the left, you see a circle bullet point appear before the first bullet. Anyone have a fix for this? I can't seem to fix it.

```
.nav
{
margin-left: 30px;
}
.nav li {
list-style:none !important;
color:black;
font-size:30px;
text-decoration:none;
}

.nav ul {
padding:0;
margin:0;
background-color: white;
}

.nav ul li {
list-style: none !important; 
float:left;
}

li > a
{  
background-image: url("media/pics/triangle.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 30px 30px;
background-position: right -10px;
} 

li > a:only-child 
{
background-image: none;
list-style-type: none;
}

.nav ul li a {
color:black;
font-size:30px;
text-decoration:none;
}

.nav li a:hover {

}

.nav ul li ul { display:none; } /* Makes the Dropdown menu Hidden by default */

.nav ul li:hover  ul  { /* Displayes the Dropdown menu when Hovered over the specific navigation item */
z-index:99999;
display:list-item !important;
position:absolute;
}

.nav ul li:hover  ul li {
float:none;
list-style:none !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zsPE9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `display:list-item !important` added on `:hover` of `.nav ul li`.

You would use `display:block`, or something other than `list-item`.

```
.nav ul li:hover ul  {
    z-index:99999;
    display:block;      /* Changed from display:list-item !important */
    position:absolute;
}
```

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eHqFL/)

Also, you should avoid usage of `!important` when possible. It essentially removes the *cascade* nature from CSS.

Comment: *facepalm* Duh! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have `display` set on `list-item`. That is probably what is causing your problem. Instead, maybe use `block` or `inline`. See other options here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp. Also, next time please just post the code that is causing the issue :).